# What is a Bipolar Country?

Tags: pattern, geography

If a country conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Bipolar Country**.
Here is a list, not exhaustive, of some Bipolar and non Bipolar countries:

| Bipolar Countries | Non bipolar Countries |
| --- | --- |
| FRANCE | JAPAN |
| ENGLAND | LAOS |
| MOROCCO | PARAGUAY |
| ITALY | SWITZERLAND |
| ARGENTINA | AUSTRALIA |
| SPAIN | CZECHIA |
| SOUTH AFRICA | AUSTRIA |
| VIETNAM | HUNGARY |
| USA | NEPAL |

CSV version:

```
Bipolar Countries,Non Bipolar Countries
France,Japan       
England,Laos   
Morocco,Paraguay      
Italy,Switzerland         
Argentina,Australia        
Spain,Iraq      
South Africa,Austria    
Vietnam,Hungary
USA,Nepal
```

Find the rule which determines whether or not a country is bipolar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bipolar country is

> A country that is not landlocked

and

> shares a land border with at least one other country

Reasoning:

> The first thing I noticed about the countries' geography was that Nepal, Austria, and Hungary were all landlocked. After looking at a map, I determined that Switzerland, Paraguay, and Czechia are as well. There were no landlocked countries among the Bipolar list. Japan and Australia are island nations that are the only countries that contain land in their respective islands.

Second step:

> After figuring out the above, I determined that the remaining countries were either part of a continent bordering both sea and another country, or England, which also borders Ireland on one of its islands.

As such,

> A bipolar country is a country that is not landlocked or a stand-alone island nation.

Comment: Then a bipolar country has rot13(gjb snprf, n frn cneg naq n ynaq cneg :)